# Installing parallel-ssh on python2.7

Tags: ssh, python

I am trying to install `parallel-ssh` on `python2.7`. My use-case for using this is to make an `ssh` connection run in parallel and not let it block further execution of a python file. I used the following command,

```
pip install parallel-ssh
```

But, I am getting the following error,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried searching for ways to rectify this. This [link](https://github.com/pkittenis/parallel-ssh/issues/54) too, but with no luck. I am not very clear on what to do and need some guidance regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts are that you have a missing dependency, you might try making sure that the python-devel/python-dev or build-essential libraries are installed (depending on your system, lots of variants). The link below has many great ideas to try out.

This link is for a similar error that has happened with installs of uwsgi.

Props to all the wise contributors:
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931726/ascii-codec-cant-decode-error-when-use-pip-to-install-uwsgi

Comment: Will try and get back.

Comment: it was an issue with an older version of pip. After upgrading the version of pip there were no issues.

Comment: Excellent find!  Thank you for sharing your success.